# POST submission with same-page action error

Tags: php, forms, session, form-submit

I have a form created on profile.php, the action is profile.php. When this form submits It seems i lose my session based off of this:

```
include_once("scripts/check_user.php");
if(!isset($_GET['user']) || $_GET['user'] == ""){
echo "Error!!_test";
$db = null;
exit();
}
```

Though I am still logged in when i refresh my profile page. Also when i submit form, it takes me to this url:

```
localhost/~michaelramos/gem/profile.php/profile.php
```

This seems to be strange as well. Here is the form:

```
<form action="profile.php" method="post">
<form is here>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
```

I create session_start() in my check user.php in the top of profile.php:

```
session_start();
include_once("dbconnect.php");
$user_is_logged = false;
$log_user_id = "";
$log_uname = "";
$log_pass = "";
```

then this file  continues to establish stye user checks.I did not include code from the action because i feel it is irrelevant.

Not entirely sure why i what all is happening here or why i get redirected to profile.php/profile.php with the error message given.

Comment: You don't happen to have a base tag set in the head of the page at all?

Comment: @Cody no, no base tags

Comment: What happens inside the check_user.php script? Any redirect calls at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came form a beginTransaction in my script, where I misplaced that coding all together.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to post data on same page then you set form action=""

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

by default form data post on same page.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you can also set the action equal to that page, either way i tried your suggestion and obtained the same result.